# Refresh in Materialized Views

Tags: sql, oracle10g, materialized-views

I have been trying to understand Materialized Views concept from a long time but was unable to get the exact functioning of it except that it is a physical table(replica) for the tables in different server.

I have tried the following

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_MV
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM TAB;
```

Here i have used `BUILD DEFERRED` so that i will get only the structure of the base table
later i can get the records using REFRESH but how do i perform REFRESH

I have even tried `BUILD IMMEDIATE` so that it will show the records but then if i have inserted new records in base table i cannot get those new records in MV.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TEMP_MV
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
FOR UPDATE
AS
SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM TAB;
```

I am using ORACLE 10G.
Please help me in understanding MV better .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify a schedule in your materialized view definition and the materialized view is not defined to refresh on commit, you would need to call [`DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96568/rarmviea.htm#94135) in order to refresh the data in the materialized view.  That is the "demand" that `REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND` refers to-- you have to tell the materialized view when you want it to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Log on base relation.
I use emp table as a base relation,and i want to update materialized view after 1 second of the commit.
So, Create Log on base relation using this query
**Create materialized view log on emp;**
then
**Create materialized view test
 
refresh fast

start with sysdate

next sysdate+(1/(24*60*60))

as

select * from emp;**

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)